# Is there any Specific Term for "the Number of Nodes/Edges in a Path" in Weighted Graphs

Tags: graph-theory, terminology

Is there a term for "the number of nodes/edges in a path" (or shortest path between two nodes) in weighted graphs?  I know that in unweighted graph it's simply the "path length" since the length equals the number of edges, but I wonder is there another term works for weighted graph, as I assume "path length" means the sum of edge weights of the path in a weighted graph.

Comment: "In a weighted graph, the length of a path is the sum of the weights of the edges encountered on the path."  https://coral.ise.lehigh.edu/~ted/files/ie172/lectures/Lecture19.pdf

Answer (score 0):

The phrases *weight of a path* and *path weight* are also used.